# Using UILongPressGestureRecognizer together with draggable MKPinAnnotationView in MKMapView

Tags: ios, mapkit, uigesturerecognizer, mkannotationview

I have having problems using a UILongPressGestureRecognizer together a draggable MKPinAnnotationView.

The behaviour I am trying to produce is similar to the Maps App.

1. The pin can be dragged.
2. When there is a long press/ tap, a pin is dropped.

However, I have problems having the long press being recognized outside the frame of the MKPinAnnotationView.  The long press gesture to drop the pin works fine if the Pin is not draggable.  When the pin is draggable however, I can't get the long press gesture recognizer to be recognized so that I can drop pin.

Any ideas?

By the way, I have tried to set the delegate for the long press recognizer so that

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

In this case, the long press gestures are recognized and the pins are dropped, but the dragging of the pin no longer works.

Snippets of the MapView (a subclass of MKMapView)

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {

    // init the gesture recognizer
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer* lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
            initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
        lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 0.5f; //user needs to press for 2 seconds
        lpgr.delegate = self;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
        [lpgr release];

        //add some initial annotation
        Marker *_annotation = [[Marker alloc] initWithCoordinate:_location];
        [_annotation titleWithString:@"some title"];
        [self addAnnotation:_annotation];

    }

    return self;

}

- (void)handleLongPress:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        return;
    }

    CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self];   
    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate = [self convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:self];

    // add marker to self-map
    // Marker is subclass of MKAnnotation
    Marker *_annotation = [[Marker alloc] initWithCoordinate:_location];
    [_annotation titleWithString:@"some title"];
    [self addAnnotation:_annotation];

}


- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>) annotation {

    if([annotation isMemberOfClass:[Marker class]] ) {

        // use MKPinAnnotationView for the view
        MKPinAnnotationView *_pin = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [mView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"spot_pin"];

        if (_pin == nil)
        {
            _pin = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"spot_pin"] autorelease];
        }
        else
        {
            _pin.annotation = annotation;
        }

        [_pin setDraggable:YES];
        [_pin setSelected:YES animated:YES];
        [_pin setCanShowCallout:YES];

        return _pin;

    } else {

        return nil;

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok guys, I solved it.

Apparently when after I subclassed MKMapView, I also added a method handleLongPress.  This method apparently interfered with the handleLongPress method of the MKMapView.

Just by changing my handleLongPress selector to a different name like handleLongPress2 will make it work like the Maps app.

```
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer* lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress2:)];
```

Comment: Please assist me i am stucking with same . drop pin nicely but how to drag that annotation .please hellp me